# How do I import Apache POI into my project for IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I'm having trouble importing Apache POI into IntelliJ.

Steps I took:

1. Download the zip file under Source Distribution on https://poi.apache.org/download.html
2. Click on File -> Project Structure -> Add New Project Library and add the zip file directory downloaded in Step 1.
3. Attempt to import apache in my main class

I tried import org.apache.poi

The error message I got is that Java could not resolve symbol 'poi' or 'apache' if poi is left out.

Comment: are you using any build tool?

Comment: I am not. I'm a bit new to Java development... crossing over from JS and front end dev. The language itself isn't difficult but adding packages is still a bit confusing for me

Comment: then you must read how to import dependency/imports at development time. If new start with eclipse, open source and free when you move to enterprise applications. (just saying)

Comment: https://github.com/pjfanning/poi-shared-strings-sample is a sample project that uses gradle (build tool). Import this into IntelliJ and it will be able to use the gradle script automatically to set up the project.